# Cannot insert new value using angular ui typeahead

Tags: angular-ui, angular-ui-typeahead

Hi have a problem angular ui typeahead: I pratically copied this sample from the angular ui page, updated to the latest version of every library.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.censimento.quartiere" placeholder="prima selezionare il comune"
       typeahead="address for address in vm.quartieri"
       typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" class="form-control" />
<i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
```

In the angular page this sample is able to select items from the list AND add leave new text in the input when I exit from the textbox, but in my application add something, the first item is automatically selected and when I leave the textbox the value of the selected item override any text i wrote.
How can I avoid this? I need to choose from the list and add new item form the same control.

Luca

Comment: Please create a Plunker that demonstrates your issue so people can better understand your setup. Also, Angular UI Bootstrap only supports AngularJS 1.2.x right now so if you're using 1.3.x, please test with 1.2.x first.

Answer (score 0):

finally I found the solution: to be able to insert text in the textbox I have to add
`typeahead-focus-first="false"`:
the default value is true and select automatically the first item. I suppose that in the version of angular ui bootstrap where I took the sample the default value was the opposite.